# How to compress an image as much as possible?

Tags: images, compression, storage

I have an image with a size of 1x1. (.png) It's a black pixel. I used Photoshop to create it as a Bitmap and when I saved it, it turned out 1.2kB+. This was not very surprising, I thought Photoshop saved a bunch of other information along with it.

When I used some programs online to compress it, I could get it down to 82 bytes, which is great, but still not exactly what I'm not looking for.

So I spent 1 hour on trials on Paint etc. but this was the best result I got. I also did research on how the images were stored in computers and learned each RGB pixel takes 3 bytes, while a pixel of a bitmap, obviously, should take 1 bit. So how come it takes 656 bits instead?

So how exactly are pictures stored? Can a pixel be compressed more?

Comment: Have you researched how image files are described? There's going to be header information to identify the file content type as well as the data of the file as well.

Comment: What is the actual question here? The thing is there are many resources online that explain what different image formats are. And a 1x1 pixel is not really a great test.

Comment: @fred_dot_u I tried to find an answer through research, but could not find what I was looking for. That was what I was suspecting. I was wondering if there was a way to get rid of the "header file" to just include the raw image so that it could have a smaller size.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 The question is, what is the smallest size an image file with 1 pixel can have, and how to achieve it? Sorry I could not make it too clear with the post.

Comment: The *"smallest image file"* would be the [raw bitmap file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format#Raw_bitmap_files) for your degenerate case.  There would be no header to indicate the type of file or format (because there simply isn't one).  There is no need to *"compress"* such a small quantity of bytes. so your title question is irrelevant.

Comment: @Qedized Fair enough. But when you say: “…which is great, but still not exactly what I'm not looking for.” I think it might be helpful for you to explain *why* you are looking to do this. You might very well be reinventing the wheel here.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I'm looking to decrease the size of a picture as low as possible. For the actual purpose, there is none. Or curiosity, whichever makes more sense.

Comment: @sawdust what a nice coincidence, I was just on that page. :D
Could you tell me if there is a way to save a bitmap as a raw image file? I've been looking for one, but not sure how those file types work...

Comment: @Qedized If the picture size matters — and not a 1x1 pixel — then your best option *might* be to explore [HEIC/HEIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Image_File_Format). compression. It is the default compression method used for photos in iOS and can be loaded in macOS. But not all systems support it yet. But in my experience a 10MB JPEG can be compressed to 1MB using [HEIC/HEIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Image_File_Format).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, what is it that you are trying to do? Some formats save extra information tacked onto the pixel values (like someone in the comments mentioned about bitmap's header information). To answer your question, you actually need to save just 1 bit to save a one pixel black image and that bit can be 0. Why? All you need to tell the computer is: I have an RGB pixel (a triplet) and the amount of "redness", "greeness" and "blueness" are all nothing, i. e., zero. We can think of it like this:

`(0, 0, 0) ≡ R = G = B = 0`

Therefore, we need *only* one bit.

Since memory is divided into words (usually 64 or 32 bit binary words), even if your number is less than `2ᵇ - 1`, your machine will still take `b` number of bits to save the number because that is the smallest unit of memory it can access.

Here is a little Python 3 program that plots your one bit black image:

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bit = 0

plt.imshow([[[bit] * 3]], cmap='Greys')
plt.show()
```

We get:

[image: One Black Pixel]

---

You want to save that information? Just save a 0 to a file? I think that will save 0 as an 8-bit (or 1 byte) Unicode character taking `b` many bits.

Comment: A script is a program therefore a python script is a python program.

Comment: The distinction you are trying to make is that it is an interpreted program since Python is an interpreted language and it is not compiled like say a C program.

Comment: Oh... When I think about it, I guess I am trying to save a 0 into a file... Which does not make much sense in a computer. Thank you very much for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

Every image file format has some level of overhead in order to provide certain features such as different bit depth support, alpha channels, metadata, compression, etc.

If you want to save a single pixel, you want the the image file format with the smallest level of overhead, such as Portable Bitmap (PBM) format, which is part of the [Netpbm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm) family of image formats.

The file:

```
P1
1 1
0
```

represents a single black pixel. Similarly, the file:

```
P1
1 1
1
```

represents a single white pixel. You can create these in any text editor, save them with the .pbm extension and open them up in Photoshop just fine.

On Windows, make sure your line breaks are CRLF, not just LF, otherwise Photoshop 2021 doesn't seem to like it. Each of these two examples is just 8 bytes.

Comment: Very interesting. So it's mostly in the format then. Thank you for your answer. Someone commented about raw files. Do you think a raw image file would be smaller?

Comment: Also, the first one is a white pixel, and the second is black for me. And it's 10 bytes rather than 8. (I'm not complaining, of course, just pointing it out.) 10 bytes is a very good improvement from 82 bytes.

Comment: A completely raw file could be just a single byte. How you interpret it as a pixel data would be up to you. It could be a single pixel representing grayscale (256 levels) or it could be an 1x8 monochrome bitmap, or 2x4 monochrome, etc., or you could discard 7 bits and treat it as a single pixel. It's up to you. But 1 byte is the lower limit.

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by not having a line break on the last line.

Comment: The interpretation part made a lot of sense. Unless you have some header on the data, you can't know what that data is. Thank you.